# SQL insert query returns false

Tags: php, mysql

Why does my query fail? The columns are there. Is there a syntax problem or should I look elsewhere?

```
 if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $result = mysqli_query
    (
     $conn, "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$username','$password')"
    );
    if($result === false) {
        echo 'query failed for some reason';
    }
    if ($end = mysqli_fetch_array($result) > 0) {
        echo "succ";
        mysql_close($conn);
    } else {
        echo 'fail';
        die('Could not insert into database:' . mysql_error());
    };
}
```

Comment: take insert query in one variable and then print that variable and see what is happening

Comment: die(mysqli_error($conn)); put it in your if condition

Comment: we can not use insert query to retrieve data from mysql

Comment: @AmanRawat I get `mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli`

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. That won't work.

Answer (score 1):

In your code if you are inserting from mysql_query
then it will not return row so you dont nead mysql_fetch_assoc()

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $result = mysqli_query
    (
     $conn, "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$username','$password')"
    );
    if($result === false) {

        echo 'query failed for some reason';
        die('Could not insert into database:' . mysqli_error($conn));
    } else {
        echo "succ";
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: returns nothing, blank screen. Is it a database problem?

Comment: returns nothing ?? is it going in if condition or in else condition

Comment: Happy to help you :) if this solves your problem accept this answer